# AngularJS - Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, scope

I've recently started using AngularJS, and even though I am able to send data through $http when the webpage loads, I'm unable to do it when a button is pressed. My code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Username: <input type="text" id="u" ng-model="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="text" id="p" ng-model="password"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" id="e" ng-model="email"><br>
    First Name: <input type="text" id="fn" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" id="ln" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="sendData()">Click me</button>
    <br>
    {{status}}
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    var arr = new Array();

    function sendData() {
        arr[0] = document.getElementById("u").value;
        arr[1] = document.getElementById("p").value;
        arr[2] = document.getElementById("e").value;
        arr[3] = document.getElementById("fn").value;
        arr[4] = document.getElementById("ln").value;

        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.post("../signup.php", {'data' : arr})
                .success(function(response) {
                    $scope.status = response.status;
                    $scope.description = response.description;
                    $scope.content = response.content;
                });
        });
    }
</script>
```

With that code, the function in app.controller doesn't execute, but if I put it outside of the sendData() function, it does execute, but right after loading the page.

Can anyone help me getting it to work when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SInce you want to use angular and you use ng-model in your view you should use ng-click on your button:

```
<button ng-click="sendData()">Click me</button>
```

Even better you can use ng-submit on your form and use a submit button.

In your controller you will have something like this:

```
$scope.username = '';
$scope.email = '';
// better have an user object here so you will not have n variables ...

$scope.sendData = function() {
     var arr = [];
     arr[0] = $scope.username;
     arr[1] = $scope.email;
     //........
     $http.post("../signup.php", {data : arr})
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.status = response.status;
            $scope.description = response.description;
            $scope.content = response.content;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the function on the scope of your controller

HTML

```
<button ng-click="sendData()">Click me</button>
```

JS

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sendData = function(
        $http.post("../signup.php", {'data' : arr})
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.status = response.status;
                $scope.description = response.description;
                $scope.content = response.content;
            });
     }
});
```